# Thin CSS borders on 3 sides bleed into a thick border on the other side

Tags: css

Top border is 6px and green. Left, right and bottom 1px #ccc.  The 1px border is bleeding into the 6px, see fiddle for an example.
http://jsfiddle.net/AzHUt/34/

Any solution other than div soup?

Comment: So you want the green top to be straightened out?

Comment: Interesting. Wasn't aware of this. It seems to be defined behaviour - I don't think you can fix this without adding another div to the equation

Comment: @Marnix Yes I want it straightened out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

for me, this looks like it works exactly like it shoud - set your border-width to 10px for all sides and 30px for the top-border to see this more clearly: http://jsfiddle.net/AzHUt/21/

if you want this to look like a "window" with an bold bar on the top, you'll need another markup ("div soup" like you said).

**EDIT:** i think this is what you've expected: http://jsfiddle.net/AzHUt/28/ - it's just a little change in the markup, adding another div to it (ugly, but it does the job)

Comment: Thanks, was just curious to see if there was away around adding that extra div. I can't even find a CSS3 solution for it.

Answer (score 1):

No; you'll need to include at least one other block: if you increase the width of the borders by a factor 10; you'll see why: all colors and widths are part of the same border; there's no way the browser can know which is "more imortant".

You don't actually need any markup changes, however; a CSS2 generated box will do too (though it's pretty hacky IMHO): http://jsfiddle.net/AzHUt/33/